# Как перевести строку байт в массив байт?

Tags: c++

Есть строка байт и нужно перевести в массив байт:

```
std::string byte = "002F4R6T";
//Нужно сделать так чтобы в конечном итоге получить
BYTE result[]  = { "00" , "2F" ,"4R" , "6T"};
```

Как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: А что такое в вашем представлении ``BYTE`, если он содержит строку из 2 символов (или указатель на нее)?...

Comment: Поддержу вопрос Harry - что такое BYTE?

Comment: @user7860670 Вы считаете 4R или там 6T — hexdump'ом?...

Comment: @Harry Очень похоже на то. Вероятно ОП опечатался в примере

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, и к тому же он не использовал 0x00, 0x2F, что было бы логично. Впрочем, конечно, без его пояснений вопрос в любом случае как минимум неполон.